# Automatic unwanted terminal outputs while solving cvxpy optimization problem

Tags: python, optimization, terminal, solver, cvxpy

While trying to solve a logistic regression problem using cvxpy I got a bunch of terminal outputs when calling the solve() function even though no print-outs were programmed. Furthermore, no information about the problem was printed to the terminal even though verbose was set to true and the optimal value could not be accessed.

I guess I'm doing something wrong in the problem formulation but can't quite figure out what it is.

The problem was defined as follows in the minimal code example:

```
import numpy as np
import cvxpy as cp

y_vec = np.random.choice([0, 1], size=(728,), p=[9./10, 1./10])
M_mat = np.random.choice([0, 1], size=(728,801), p=[9./10, 1./10])
beta = cp.Variable(M_mat.shape[0])
objective = 0
for i in range(400):
    objective += y_vec[i] * M_mat[:, i].T @ beta - \
        cp.log(1 + cp.exp((M_mat[:, i].T @ beta)))

prob = cp.Problem(cp.Maximize(objective))
prob.solve(verbose=True)
print("Optimal var reached",  beta.value)
```

Both `y_vec` and `M_mat` are numpy arrays with data type int64. Both are selection matrices for the classification problem consisting of only 0 and 1. For the purpose of the minimal code example they are randomly generated to reproduce the error. Furthermore `M_mat[:, i].T @ beta` was checked to result in a scalar as intended.

When i execute the code i get printouts a lot of printouts like these with the program terminating after a certain number.

[image: End of the terminal print out after which the program is terminated]

Shown here is only the end of the print outs when the program terminates. But there are many blocks of the form `log(1.0 + exp([ 0. 0. ...... 0.] * var0))` where this output sequence is of the same length as the variable beta.

I find this result quite confusing. How can i arrive at a single vector for the optimization argument beta? Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: Please provide a minimal complete example that can be run.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. The problem is now adjusted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some trial and error i found out that using the cvxpy.logistic()function somehow results in a successful computation of the solution with a desired output vector.

This was achieved by reformulating the objective function as follows:

```
objective = 0
for i in range(400):
    objective += y_vec[i] * M_mat[:, i].T @ beta - cp.logistic(M_mat[:, i].T @ beta)
```

Even though both implementations should mathematically be the same according to [Atomic Functions - CVXPY](https://www.cvxpy.org/tutorial/functions/index.html) it results in drastically different outputs. Why this is the case i don't know. I hope the solution might nonetheless be useful for somebody and I'm curious to know more why the behavior is so different if someone knows more.

Comment: it tells me i can only accept my own answer tomorrow. So i will do that tomorrow :)

Comment: Excellent. Thank you for following up and posting it (many people never bother).

Comment: Your welcome! May i ask if you think it might be worth it to do a follow up question to ask whether someone knows why this two different behaviors exist? Even if i can continue my work now i guess this is hardly the way its intended in cvxpy. Maybe it might even be worth a bug report?

Comment: CVXPY knows the curvature of the logistic function is convex, as mentioned in the atomic functions documentation. It doesn't know that cp.log(1+cp.exp(x)) is convex, because that expression doesn't follow DCP rules.

Answer (score 2):

Your original formulation of the problem is not [DCP-compliant](https://www.cvxpy.org/tutorial/dcp/index.html). I admit the output is far from ideal; CVXPY is printing the expressions that are not DCP-compliant, but there are so many of them that the output is useless. Replacing the `400` in your for loop with `1`, you get the following output, which is more helpful because it fits in your terminal window.

```
The objective is not DCP. Its following subexpressions are not:
log(1.0 + exp([0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 1. 0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.
 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.
 0. 0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 0. 1. 0. 1. 0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.
 1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.
 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.
 0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.
 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 0.
 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 0.
 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 0.
 1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.
 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.
 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.
 1. 0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.
 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.
 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 0. 0.
 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.
 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.
 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 0. 0.
 0. 0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.
 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.
 1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 1. 0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.
 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 0. 0.
 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.
 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 0. 1. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1.
 0. 0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0.
 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.
 0. 1. 0. 0. 1. 0. 1. 0. 0. 1. 1. 0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 1. 0. 1. 0.
 0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.
 0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.
 0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 1. 0. 0.
 0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 1. 0. 0.] @ var6400))
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Yes that phrase would have helped quite a bit!